# Adding event hovertext in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to include a hover text on events in a month calendar page of full calendar.

I have and array object declaring the events that need to be on the page as loaded in by a php script. It looks as followed:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
events: [
    {
        title  : 'event1',
        start  : '2010-01-01'
    },
    {
        title  : 'event2',
        start  : '2010-01-05',
        end    : '2010-01-07'
    }
]
```

});

I am trying to use the eventMouseover function to include a hover text with each event. This function's prototype is as followed: function( event, jsEvent, view ) { } Where event is the event object, jsEvent is the native JavaScript event with low-level information such as mouse coordinates. and the view holds the view object of fullcalendar. I am not able to correctly call the arguments of this function.  My info is coming from here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventMouseover/ and I'm totally cool with other ways of achieving a hovertext on each event. Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're on the right track. I did something similar to show the event end time at the bottom of the event in agenda view.

**Options on the calendar:**

```
eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    $('.fc-event-inner', this).append('<div id=\"'+event.id+'\" class=\"hover-end\">'+$.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, 'h:mmt')+'</div>');
}

eventMouseout: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#'+event.id).remove();
}
```

**CSS for the hover over:**

```
.hover-end{padding:0;margin:0;font-size:75%;text-align:center;position:absolute;bottom:0;width:100%;opacity:.8}
```

Hopefully this helps you!

Comment: I have passed two event sources. Is it possible to show hover for only one event source?

Answer (score 9):

Without bootstrap, even simpler to add just browser tooltip with

```
eventRender : function(event, element) {
   element[0].title = event.title;
}
```

Comment: Worked for me! Actually should be the answer.

Comment: v5 now requires eventDidMount: function(info) {
               info.el.title = info.event.title;
            },

Answer (score 4):

If you are using bootstrap, this is very elegant solution:

```
 eventRender: function(event, element) {
     $(element).tooltip({title: event.title});
 }
```

(I got it from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27922934/2941313)

Comment: will this work on multiple tooltips? i tried ````tooltip({title: event.title,description: event.description});```` but it didn't worked.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you need. I don't think description is a part of bootstrap tooltip, right? If you could be more precise, then maybe I could assist you further.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using fullcalendar version5:

eventMouseEnter: function(info) {info.el.title = info.event.start;},

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

For me this is what I did as I needed to mod other great answers.

HTML:

```
(eventRender)="addHoverTitle($event)"
```

Component:

```
addHoverTitle(args: any): void {
   args.el.title = args.event.title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In version 4 of FullCalendar, there is only one argument: eventRender: function (info) so the snippet is:

WORK WITH BOOTSTRAP

```
eventRender: function (info) {
  $(info.el).tooltip({ title: info.event.title });
}
```

Comment: Most people want an answer not involving addition libraries or frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Angular**

Html :

```
<full-calendar 
 ...
 (eventLeave)="eventLeave($event)">
</full-calendar>
```

Typescript:

```
eventRender($event) {
  $event.el.title = $event.event.title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Calendar options I used this for my angular project:

```
eventMouseEnter: function (calEvent) {
    calEvent.el.title = calEvent.event.title;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            eventDidMount: function(info) {
                if(info.view.type!='timeGridDay'){
                    $(info.el).tooltip({ title: info.event.title });    
                }
            }
```

for v4 we can use "eventRender"
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventRender

for v5,v6 we can use "eventDidMount"
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object