# fullcalendar with clickable popup on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar, qtip

I need a pop up on hover full calendar like [this one](http://www.discoveryeducation.com/Events/).

Have tried full calendar with qtip but could not get clickable popup its disappers when mouse is out from the spot.

Here's a [similar example](http://jsfiddle.net/ramsunvtech/XyNnH/) but it need to create a clickable popup like that of above example

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var events_array = [
        {
            title: 'Test1',
            start: new Date(2012, 8, 20),
            tip: 'Personal tip 1'
        },
        {
            title: 'Test2',
            start: new Date(2012, 8, 21),
            tip: 'Personal tip 2'
        }
    ];

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        events: events_array,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.attr('title', event.tip);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

heres my code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup FullCalendar
// Setup FullCalendar
(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var tooltip = $('<div/>').qtip({
        id: 'fullcalendar',
        prerender: true,
        content: {
            text: ' ',
            title: {
                button: true
            }
        },
        position: {
            my: 'bottom center',
            at: 'top center',
            target: 'mouse',
            viewport: $('#fullcalendar'),
            adjust: {
                mouse: false,
                scroll: false
            }
        },
        show: false,
        hide: false,
        style: 'qtip-light'
    }).qtip('api');

    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        height: 600,
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        eventMouseover : function(data, event, view) {
            var content = '<h3>'+data.title+'</h3>' + 
                '<p><b>Start:</b> '+data.start+'<br />' + 
                (data.end && '<p><b>End:</b> '+data.end+'</p>' || '');

            tooltip.set({
                'content.text': content
            })
            .reposition(event).show(event);
        },
        dayClick: function() { tooltip.hide() },
        eventResizeStart: function() { tooltip.hide() },
        eventDragStart: function() { tooltip.hide() },
        viewDisplay: function() { tooltip.hide() },
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1)
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                allDay: false
            }
        ]
    });
}());
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 37):

Use Bootstrap tooltip plugin http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips . And then inside eventRender callback write following:

```
 eventRender: function(event, element) {
      $(element).tooltip({title: event.title});             
  }
```

This will work

[image]

Comment: Works great but I'm having some issue with the 'agendaWeek' view, tooltip stick into the column

Comment: This answer does not address the important part of the question, "could not get clickable popup its disappers when mouse is out "

Answer (score 12):

check this example. http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/N78hs/

```
eventClick: function(data, event, view) {
            var content = '<h3>'+data.title+'</h3>' + 
                '<p><b>Start:</b> '+data.start+'<br />' + 
                (data.end && '<p><b>End:</b> '+data.end+'</p>' || '');

            tooltip.set({
                'content.text': content
            })
            .reposition(event).show(event);
        }
```

it works on click, not in hover, but you can adapt it to work in hover as well

Comment: jsfiddle now broken

Answer (score 11):

```
eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
    var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:#ccc;position:absolute;z-index:10001;">' + calEvent.title + '</div>';
    $("body").append(tooltip);
    $(this).mouseover(function(e) {
        $(this).css('z-index', 10000);
        $('.tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
        $('.tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
    }).mousemove(function(e) {
        $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
        $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
    });
},

eventMouseout: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
     $(this).css('z-index', 8);
     $('.tooltipevent').remove();
},
```

Answer (score 4):

In version 4 of FullCalendar, there is only one argument:
eventRender: function (info)

so the snippet is:

```
eventRender: function (info) {
  $(info.el).tooltip({ title: info.event.title });     
}
```

Comment: Men... u r a genius! :)

Answer (score 3):

I am doing this within Shopify with jQuery already active.

I downloaded the bootstrap Tooltip plugin but actually preferred using the popover plugin.

Having linked to the necessary bootstrap CSS and JS files I then had the following below. If you rather use tooltip you what I had worked, but I commented it out in preference of popover.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                defaultView: 'month',
                //eventBackgroundColor: 'red',
                //weekends: false,
                eventTextColor: '#FFFFFF',
                hiddenDays: [ 0 ],

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,'
        },

//              eventRender: function(event, element) {
//                  $(element).tooltip({title: event.description});             
//              },

        eventRender: function(event, element) {
          $(element).popover({title: event.title, content: event.description, trigger: 'hover', placement: 'auto right', delay: {"hide": 300 }});             
        },

        googleCalendarApiKey: 'XXXXXX',      

        eventSources: [
         {//BEGINNERS ACTING FUN
            googleCalendarId: 'XXXXX',
            color: '#990000',   // an option!
        },
         {//INTERMEDIATES SCENE WORK
            googleCalendarId: 'XXXX',
            color: 'purple',   // an option!  
        },
           {//INTERMEDIATES SCENE WORK
            googleCalendarId: 'XXX',
            color: 'blue',   // an option!  
        },


        {// VOICE & COMMUNICATION SKILLS
            googleCalendarId: 'XXXX',
            color: 'green',   // an option!
        }

        ]

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer based on @Divyank Sabhaya's solution to work on v4

```
eventMouseEnter: function(calEvent) {
var tooltip = '<div class="tooltipevent" style="width:auto;height:20px;vertical-align:middle;background:'+calEvent.el.style.backgroundColor+';position:absolute;z-index:10001;">' + calEvent.event._def.extendedProps.description + '</div>';
$("body").append(tooltip);
$(this.el).mouseover(function(e) {
    $(this.el).css('z-index', 10000);
    $('.tooltipevent').fadeIn('500');
    $('.tooltipevent').fadeTo('10', 1.9);
}).mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.tooltipevent').css('top', e.pageY + 10);
    $('.tooltipevent').css('left', e.pageX + 20);
});},

eventMouseLeave: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
 $(this.el).css('z-index', 8);
 $('.tooltipevent').remove();},
```

best

Answer (score -1):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup FullCalendar
// Setup FullCalendar
(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var tooltip = $('<div/>').qtip({
        id: 'fullcalendar',
        prerender: true,
        content: {
            text: ' ',
            title: {
                button: true
            }
        },
        position: {
            my: 'bottom center',
            at: 'top center',
            target: 'mouse',
            viewport: $('#fullcalendar'),
            adjust: {
                mouse: false,
                scroll: false
            }
        },
        show: false,
        hide: false,
        style: 'qtip-light'
    }).qtip('api');

    $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        height: 600,
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        eventMouseover : function(data, event, view) {
            var content = '<h3>'+data.title+'</h3>' + 
                '<p><b>Start:</b> '+data.start+'<br />' + 
                (data.end && '<p><b>End:</b> '+data.end+'</p>' || '');

            tooltip.set({
                'content.text': content
            })
            .reposition(event).show(event);
        },
        dayClick: function() { tooltip.hide() },
        eventResizeStart: function() { tooltip.hide() },
        eventDragStart: function() { tooltip.hide() },
        viewDisplay: function() { tooltip.hide() },
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 1)
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                allDay: false
            }
        ]
    });
}());
    });

</script>
```