# mouseover event hover info box with FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I really like the hovering info box used on this site with Fullcalendar: http://www.bigwood.nottingham.sch.uk/calendar

Does anyone know how I can achieve something similar with a non wordpress site?  I would like people to be able to hover over the event on my Fullcalendar google calendar so that they get all the details of my pilates classes - here is my test page: http://www.pilatesintuition.co.uk/test/pilates-classes.html

I am not a programmer or coder, so please forgive me for my ignorance!

Many thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site strictly for programming related questions, and does not address requests for tutorials, etc. If you do not have any experience coding you might want to ask this question elsewhere.

Comment: I don't mean to breach any rules, just that the site where I downloaded FullCalendar: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/usage/ says to post any support questions here - that is what I have done.  I am asking how to add this hover function to FullCalendar.  I don't really know where else I can ask for help with FullCalendar since the author of it says people can't email him direct :-(  Sorry.

Comment: Don't worry, you wouldn't have known. It's actually considered very bad practice for other sites to tell their users to post support questions here, because that's simply not what this site is for. Unfortunately I know next to nothing about FullCalendar, so my best advice would be to try googling for a tutorial. Good luck!

Comment: I have just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448097/fullcalendar-with-clickable-popup-on-hover - so going to digest and see what happens - scary as I am just a Pilates teacher, lol!

Comment: Fantastic! I hope that you can find a reasonable solution there.

Comment: Don't worry too much. You can't (easily) accidentally break anything. Hope you get it to work, but if not (and you have a concrete question) don't be afraid to ask here. Programming is meant to be fun! And imagine how proud you will be of yourself if you can get it to work *just the way you want*.

Comment: Well, I have found a few answers and seems qtip is the way to go, but lots of people seem to be having problems integrating qtip with FullCalendar.  I have set up a new question so this one can be closed now.  Many thanks.