# Tooltip for primeng- schedule events

Tags: fullcalendar, primeng

[image]
Below is the Primeng-schedule that I have created in Angular2. I am able to add events to the calendar. I have added events for days click, left and right arrow.

I am looking for tooltip on mousehover for events and days. Is that feature available.

```
  <p-schedule [events]="events" [eventLimit] ="3" (onViewRender)="loadEvents($event)" (onEventClick)="handleEventClick($event)" 
    (onDayClick)="handleDayClick($event)" ></p-schedule>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448097/fullcalendar-with-clickable-popup-on-hover for hovering over events.

Comment: P.S. Why are you using the "viewRender" callback to load events? You can do it directly via the "events" property. Read the documentation on the various types of dynamic event feed supported: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<p-schedule [events]="events" [header]="headerConfig" (onViewRender)="loadEvents($event)" (onEventMouseover)="handleMouseOver($event,op)" (onEventClick)="handleEventClick($event)">
</p-schedule>
    <p-overlayPanel appendTo="body" #op>
        <label>Title:{{popOverTitle}}</label>
    </p-overlayPanel>
```

TS

```
    handleMouseOver(e, op) {
        this.popOverTitle = e.calEvent.title;
        op.show(e, e.jsEvent.target);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no directly an option for tooltip in fullcalendar. But you can use external libraries. Fullcalendar offers [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/) in their [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/).
There is an example for you with fullcalendar & qtip2 .

```
jsfiddle.net/N78hs/1649/
```